# Why does the complex logarithm have different branches?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, logarithms

I have a question regarding the complex logarithm which I have studied a long time ago, therefore not everything is clear anymore.

If I remember it correctly then the general complex logarithm is defined to be the solution of $e^{w}=z$. So I mean then in this case if we write $z=re^{i\theta}$ we say that $$w=\log(r)+i(\theta+2\pi k)$$for all $k\in \Bbb{N}$. Did I understand this correctly?

Now I also know that we define the natural branch of logarithm as $$\log:\Bbb{C}\rightarrow \Bbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$$ where $\log(re^{i\theta})=\log(r)+i\theta$ where $\theta\in [-\pi, \pi)$. First, I don’t see how we get from the general definition to this one with natural branch.  And in addition, why do we here take out the negative real axis? Is this because for example $-1$ the definition would not make sense since $$\log(-1e^{i-\pi})=log(-1)+(-\pi i)$$ and this means $-\pi i=0$?

What is the detailed explanation?

Comment: The only point you need to exclude is $0$, since $\log(0)$ is not defined. Also note lat the radius for $-1$ is $1$.

Comment: The answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4246914/121671) may provide more details to your question. One can remove any ray from the origin to define a branch of log; removing the negative axis for example you get a branch that contains the unit ball of radius 1 centered at $1$. this is related to the basic function $\log(1-x)$ from Calculus, and that maybe (historically) why that brach is the "natural one".

Comment: What do you mean by *"therefore not scything is clear anymore."* (seems incomprehensible)? Can you elaborate?

Comment: "be the solution of $e^w=z$" is not right: given $z$, solutions to the equation $e^w=z$ are not unique. You may use "the solution *set*". See definition (1) [below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4444601/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\def\Log{\operatorname{Log}}$$\def\arg{\operatorname{arg}}$$\def\cbf{\mathbf{C}}$$\def\zbf{\mathbf{Z}}$$\def\rbf{\mathbf{R}}$**The complex logarithm.**

The complex logarithm is a multi-valued function, which can be formally written as
$$
\log(z) = \{w\in\cbf:e^w=z\}\;\tag{1}
$$
When $z$ is nonzero, it can be written as
$$
\log(z) = \ln|z|+i\arg(z)
$$
where $\arg(z):=\{\theta\in\rbf:\cos\theta+i\sin\theta=\frac{z}{|z|}\}$. Here we use $\ln$ for the natural logarithm of positive real numbers.

So, for instance,
$$
\log(2i)=\{\ln 2+\frac{\pi i}{2}+2k\pi i: k\in\zbf\}\;.
$$
The complex exponential never vanishes, so by our definition (1), $\log(0)$ is the empty set. This is usually why people omit the origin from the domain $\mathbf{C}$ when discussing complex logarithm.

**Branches?**

Let $U$ be a non-empty open subset of $\cbf\setminus\{0\}$. A function $f:U\to\cbf$ is called a *branch* of the complex logarithm, if $f(z)\in \log(z)$ for every $z\in U$. It other words, for each $z\in U$, the branch $f$ picks a value $f(z)$ in the set $\log(z)$.

There are many choices of branches for the complex logarithm. We are interested in those have good properties such as homomorphicity (analyticity).

It turns out that if $U=\cbf\setminus\{0\}$, then there is no branch $f:U\to \cbf$ of $\log$ that is holomorphic (in $U$). In other words, no matter how you pick the value $f(z)$ for each $z\in U$, the function $f$ will never be holomorphic on all of $U$.

On the other hand, if $U$ is a *simply connected open subset* of $\cbf\setminus\{0\}$, we can define a branch $f:U\to\cbf$ that is holomorphic (on all of $U$). For instance the region $U=\cbf\setminus (-\infty,0]$ formed by excluding the negative real axis from the complex plane is simply connected and so must admit a holomorphic branch of the complex logarithm. One such branch is the *standard branch* $\Log:\cbf\setminus (-\infty,0]\to\cbf$, defined as
$$
\Log(z):=\ln|z|+i\operatorname{Arg}(z)\tag{2}
$$
where $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ is the standard branch of the argument, defined as the unique argument in $\arg(z)$ in the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$.

**Examples.**

> ... why do we here take out the negative real axis?

We don't have to, this is just one way to get a simply connected open subset of the punctured complex plane $\cbf\setminus\{0\}$. But we have to take out *something* in order to get a holomorphic branch.

[Edited.] There are many other ways to get holomorphic branches of the logarithm.

You can pick another branch of the $\arg(z)$ in (2). For instance, define for $z\in\cbf\setminus(-\infty,0]$,
$$
f(z)=\ln|z|+i\theta
$$
where $\theta$ is the unique argument in $\arg(z)$ in the interval $(3\pi,5\pi]$.

Then in this branch, you have
$$
f(1+i)=\ln(\sqrt{2})+i(4\pi+\frac{\pi}{4})\;,
$$
while in the standard branch, you have
$$
\Log(1+i)=\ln(\sqrt{2})+i(\frac{\pi}{4})\;.
$$

Or you can change the domain $\cbf\setminus (-\infty,0]$ to some other simply connected open subset of $\cbf\setminus \{0\}$, e.g., $U=\cbf\setminus [0,+\infty)$, and then choose a branch of the argument function.

For instance, let $f:\cbf\setminus [0,+\infty)\to\cbf$ be
$$
f(z)=\ln|z|+i\theta\tag{3}
$$
where $\theta$ is the unique argument in $\arg(z)$ in the interval $(0,2\pi)$.

Comment: Thank you for the really nice answer. There are still some points which I don't see yet. I somehow can't imagine what a branch is geometrically, because the definition looks really abstract to me. So I mean is $f$ in the definition of the branch the logarithm function? Then secondly  did I understood it correctly, that we need to find a simply connected subset of $\Bbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ to define a holomorphic branch, but then for such a branch we always write $\log(re^{it})=\log(r)+i(\theta+2\pi k)$ but we only have a unique $k$ in each branch?

Comment: Sorry for my confusion I don't understand this yet. Because I don't see if I take for example $U=\Bbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty)$ how we define our logarithm and how we get there.

Comment: I edited the answer. Please read the examples at the end. "... how we define our logarithm" *The* complex logarithm is by definition (1), there is only one such thing;  it maps each $z$ to the *set* of solutions $\{w:e^w=z\}$.  What we define later instead, is a *branch* of the logarithm, which by abuse of language, sometimes is also called "a" complex logarithm.

Comment: Using definition (1), you have $\log(re^{it})=\{\ln(r)+i(t+2k\pi): k\in\mathbf{Z}\}$. Note that the right-hand side is a *set*. In a specific branch, you pick a unique $k$ *for each* $re^{it}$ in the domain $U$ of the branch.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. First of all, can we then think about the branch as the intervall where our argument lives in?

Comment: Now is it true that if I take the branch as in your last example so $f:\Bbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty)\rightarrow \Bbb{C}$ with $z\mapsto \log(z)+i\theta$ where $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ then I have $$\log(1+i)=\log\left(\sqrt{2}\right)+i\frac{\pi}{4}$$ but I can also take $\theta\in [2\pi,4\pi)$ then $$\log(1+i)=\log\left(\sqrt{2}\right)+i\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi\right)$$ So did I do this correct

Comment: @Wave: you are welcome. At this point, it is *very* confusing to abuse the notation.  I would stick to the definitions used in this answer: if one wants to talk about *the* complex logarithm defined in (1), one should use $\log$; if one wants to talk about a specific *branch* $f:U\to\mathbf{C}$ of the logarithm, then use the notation $f$; if one is particularly talking about the *real* natural logarithm, then one uses $\ln$. It makes everything unnecessarily confusing and complicated if one uses "$\log$" for all three cases.

Comment: @Wave: "can we then think about the branch as the interval where our argument lives in" For *holomorphic* branches, yes; the argument must various continuously. For crazy branches that don't retain any good properties, the choice of argument is completely arbitrary.

Comment: @Wave: in the example in your comment, you almost have it right except notation confusion. You can define a branch $f:\mathbf{C}\setminus[0,\infty)\to\mathbf{C}$ with $f(z)=\ln(|z|)+i\theta$ where $\theta$ is the argument of $z$ that lie in the interval $[0,2\pi)$. Then $f(1+i)=\ln(\sqrt{2})+i\frac{\pi}{4}$. If you define another branch $g:\mathbf{C}\setminus[0,\infty)\to\mathbf{C}$ with $g(z)=\ln(|z|)+i\theta$ where $\theta$ is the argument of $z$ that lie in the interval $[2\pi,4\pi)$, then $g(1+i)=\ln(\sqrt{2})+i(2\pi+\frac{\pi}{4})$. These two are both holomorphic branches.

Comment: Ah I see so there is the abuse of notation which plays a role. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $w\in\Bbb C$ is a logarithm of $z\in\Bbb C$ if $e^w=z$. And, yes, if $z=re^{i\theta}$ and $w$ is a logarithm of $z$, then $w=\log(r)+i(\theta+2k\pi)$, for some $k\in\Bbb Z$.

Usually, if we can work only with complex numbers $z\in\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$, we work with the main logarithm $\log\colon\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ which is such that $\log(re^{i\theta})=\log(r)+i\theta$ (assuming that $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi)$). Note that $\log(r)+i\theta$ is a logarithm of $z$ and that it is the simplest one. That makes it a natural choice.

So, why don't we extend this to a map from $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ into $\Bbb C$? We could do it if we mapped $re^{i\theta}$ ($\theta\in[-\pi,\pi)$) into $\log(r)+i\theta$. Problem: this would not be a continuous function anymore. And there is nothing wrong with the interval $[-\pi,\pi)$; if we had used the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$, we would have the same problem.

More generally, there is *no* continuous function $l\colon\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ such that, for every $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$, $l(z)$ is a logarithm of $z$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added in the answer above some comments, which I could also add here but they would be the same so I thought I only post them once. Maybe you could also take a look because maybe you see where I'm stuck

Comment: There is no such thing as *the* logarithm function from a subset of $\Bbb C$ into $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Yes I see but somehow I don't see what this branch means geometrically and also how to get from the branch to the "definition" of the logarithm so from where to where my $\theta$ goes in which branch ect.